# Android: Refresh current fragment after language change

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, layout, refresh

So my `MainActivity` has a navigation drawer with a set of fragments.

On top of the nav bar, I have 2 flags which represent a language. If an user clicks on a language, the app changes the language of the whole app.

Everything is working smoothly (activity refreshes, navigation drawer and all fragments get translated) but the fragment that's open doesn't. This means that the user needs to click on the navigation drawer and select the fragment again to see it translated.

[image]

How can I refresh the current fragment the user is in?

Answer (score 2):

Add tag to your fragment when you commit it:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.your_id, fragment, "Your_Fragment_TAG").commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Then You can detach and attach again your fragment for refresh:

```
// Reload current fragment
Fragment frg = null;
frg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Your_Fragment_TAG");
final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. I've seen this piece of code but this doesn't work at runtime. Since `Your_Fragment_TAG` is not known if I'm right?

Comment: Yeah, because you need to set the tag before you call findFragmentByTag

Comment: Is there another piece of code that works @ runtime? or am I obliged to notice this to the user (as a toast) or restart the complete app? What are my options?

Comment: Do you change the strings programmatically? or you changed the configuration locale?

Comment: The configuration locale method (using another values-xx folder containing strings.xml)

Comment: So you need to restart the complete app as you said.