# Change language for the whole application inside a fragment?

Tags: c#, localization, xamarin.android

Let's say this is the call stack:

> Fragment2 (current position)
>
> Fragment1
>
> HostingActivity

The user has just navigated to fragment2 (which is the settings screen). He chooses a second language, and then navigates back to Fragment1. I want the app to show content from the second language as soon as he enters fragment1.

I've read that the best approach would be to let all the fragments derive from a base-fragment which configures the locale inside the `OnResume()` method.

```
public class BaseFragment : Fragment
{
    public override void OnResume()
    {
        string langCode = prefs.GetString("settings_language", "en_US");

        Resources res = Application.Context.Resources;
        // Change locale settings in the app.
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.DisplayMetrics;
        Configuration conf = res.Configuration;
        conf.SetLocale(new Locale(langCode.ToLower()));

        res.UpdateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        OnConfigurationChanged(conf);

        base.OnResume();
    }
}
```

I've attempted this, but without any luck. I didn't see any change whatsoever.
I'm open to hear any suggestions.

*PS. To ensure that I didn't mess up any of the naming conventions required by Android in the values folder, I tried rebooting the emulator (with adb shell) using the language I wanted and it worked as expected.*

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT I'm not entirely sure how the use of `tags` would make any difference. Could you explain that further?

Comment: Refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38022709/android-refresh-current-fragment-after-language-change

Answer (score 0):

You can create a base class that sets the `CurrentCulture` like this and inherit from it:

```
internal class MyBaseActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnResume ()
    {
        base.OnResume ();

        // Get the language from wherever.
        var userSelectedCulture = new CultureInfo ("fr-FR");

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = userSelectedCulture;
    }
}
```

And here is how to inherit and use it:

```
public class MainActivity : MyBaseActivity
{
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();  // Do not forget to call base.OnResume()
        // Rest of Your Code...
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this works for activities, but as I mentioned - I've tried this approach and I'm having a hard time making this work with fragments. Have you had any luck using this method with fragments?